# Wordpress, get a post content by its name or URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I saw in here that I can get a post's content in WordPress using the post ID. Something like:

```
<?php $my_postid = 83;//This is page id or post id
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;?>
```

I want the very same thing, BUT getting the post by its name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using

```
$content_post = get_posts( array( 'name' => 'yourpostname' ) ); // i.e. hello-world
if( count($content_post) )
{
    $content = $content_post[0]->post_content;
    // do whatever you want
    echo $content;
}
```

**Update :** Also you can add this function in your `functions.php` and can call it from anywhere

```
function get_post_by_name($post_name, $post_type = 'post', $output = OBJECT) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s", $post_name, $post_type ));
    if ( $post ) return get_post($post, $output);
    return null;
}

// call the function "get_post_by_name"
$content_post = get_post_by_name('hello-world');
if($content_post)
{
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    // do whatever you want
    echo $content;
}
```

**Update :** To get a post by it's **title** you can use

```
// 'Hello World!' is post title here
$content_post = get_page_by_title( 'Hello World!', OBJECT, 'post' );
```

or  you can use your `$item->item_title` variable

```
$content_post = get_page_by_title( $item->item_title, OBJECT, 'post' );
if($content_post)
{
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    // do whatever you want
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: it works if I put the post name manually. But what if I want it to be dynamic <?php echo ( $item->item_title); ?>. I mean, I don't know php I'm asking you what to put inside 'yourpostname' if i want to put the itemtitle as postname...

Comment: `post-name` is post `slug` here and it's not title but if you want to use title instead, then you can use [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).